# How to subscribe to all wiki.ubuntu.com page changes

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

I can subscribe to each wiki.ubuntu.com page individually but some users are notified on each change.
How to add myself to be also notified on each change?
And how to remove?
Im still getting even after removing myself.
[image]

Comment: Ouch. I am so sorry. :(

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to the wiki.ubuntu.com using your credentials.
2. Click on your username.
3. Click on *Notifications*.
4. In the box meant for *Subscribed wiki pages (one regex per line)*, choose the pages you want to subscribe to.

   - You can use [this wiki help page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HelpOnSubscribing) for reference on what regex to use for which pages.
5. Save your changes and expect loads of email to reach you after that.